# How to add methods to a has_many collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assuming a typical has_many association

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

How can I add a method to the collection of orders? For the sake of code organization, I'm trying to reactor this method (this is a made-up example) inside of my `Customer` class:

```
def update_orders
  ThirdPartyAPI.look_up(self.orders) do |order|
    # Do stuff to the orders
    # May need to access 'self', the Customer...
  end
end
```

I don't like this because it puts a lot of knowledge about the `Order` class inside my `Customer` class. I can't use an instance method off of an order, since the ThirdPartyAPI can do a batch lookup on multiple orders. I could make a static method off of `Order` and pass in the array of orders, and their parent customer, but this feels clunky.

I found this in the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions), but I couldn't find any good examples of how to use this in practice. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 6):

I think this should do it

```
has_many :entities do
  def custom_function here

  end

  def custom_function here

  end 
end
```